# Use JQ "contains" and suppress errors when key not found

Tags: json, shell, try-catch, jq

I am trying to get the value based on the "contains" value of another key in the same object

I have already tried a code and it works and outputs the result that I want, but some objects in the JSON do not have this key as such I get:

`jq: error (at <stdin>:1): null (null) and string ("BBC") cannot have their containment checked`

or the reason for this error are the arrays in other keys, I am not sure

Using:

`jq '.entries[] | select(.icon | contains("BBC")) | .uuid'`

*I want the UUID of the found result with no errors and store it as a variable in shell*

`"174501xxxxxxxxxxxxxe6342a03"`

Input file that is piped

```
{  
   "entries":[  
      {  
         "uuid":"174501xxxxxxxxxxxxxe6342a03",
         "enabled":true,
         "autoname":true,
         "name":"BBC",
         "number":0,
         "icon":"file:///logos/BBC.png",
         "icon_public_url":"imagecache/1097",
         "epgauto":true,
         "epggrab":[  ],
         "dvr_pre_time":0,
         "dvr_pst_time":0,
         "epg_running":-1,
         "services":[  ],
         "tags":[  ],
         "bouquet":""
      },
      {  
         "uuid":"174501xxxxxxxxxxxxxe6342a04",
         "enabled":true,
         "autoname":true,
         "name":"ABC",
         "number":0,
         "icon_public_url":"imagecache/1098",
         "epgauto":true,
         "epggrab":[  ],
         "dvr_pre_time":0,
         "dvr_pst_time":0,
         "epg_running":-1,
         "services":[  ],
         "tags":[  ],
         "bouquet":""
      }...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is more than one way to achieve this with jq. You could use conditionals and branching but I think the simplest way is using `try-catch` without the `catch` to just silence any error. The documentation is at the end of [Conditionals and Comparisons](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#ConditionalsandComparisons)

Here is [an example](https://jqplay.org/s/nA2ez_Y8l3) that will simply omit the error and only print the UUIDs if there is no error for that object:

`.entries[] | select(.icon | try contains("BBC")) | .uuid`

Comment: that is so simple. Thanks. But why am I getting 2 outputs (duplicate), when there is only 1 match?

Comment: Are you referring to the output of my linked example? I added a second copy of the entry that satisfies the select statement to make sure that it would return all UUIDs.  In [this new example](https://jqplay.org/s/0WUI1vbVw1) I modified one of the UUIDs so you can see that two separate matches are being returned.

Comment: Did this not answer your question?

Comment: You may use `contains("BBC")?` as a synonym for `try contains("BBC")`.

Answer (score 5):

You can preselect only objects that have the `icon` key with `has("icon")`.

From the [jq 1.5 Manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#has(key)):

> `has(key)`
>
> The builtin function `has` returns whether the input object
>   has the given key, or the input array has an element at the given
>   index.

```
jq '.entries[] | select(has("icon")) | select(.icon | contains("BBC")).uuid' file
```

However, it will output an error if your object has `"icon":null` in which case you could use:

```
jq '.entries[] | select(.icon != null) | select(.icon | contains("BBC")).uuid' file
```

Comment: might sound trivial but would "throwing" away the error be the fastest execution time?

Comment: @mfaiz I made an oopsie. Please ignore my previous attempts. I had no idea `jq` would actually stop when it encounters error such as this one.

Comment: nevertheless still a more "correct" way to approach it rather than ignoring the answer. between this and try catch method i suppose the try method has a faster execution time since there is one less jq command to pipe

Comment: @mfaiz I am no `jq` expert, but the `try` is certainly not free either. The execution times shouldn't differ much. Testing with an array of `300,000` objects, my `has` solution ran `6,342s`, `!= null` solution `6,496s` and the `try` solution `6,483s`. As you can see, the time different is not big, the correctness is a different question :)

Comment: has it is then!